# How to remove rows that are all zeros from SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Should be simple to do this but cannot make it work.  Have also looked at other similar answers.  This code generates a report.  There are 3 primary categories: General Adjustments, Finance Charges, and Bad Debts.  What I am trying to accomplish...

If these 3 columns are all zeros in a row, delete that row.  That's it.

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME
DECLARE @lastdate DATETIME

SET @startdate = '20170701'
SET @lastdate = '20170731'

CREATE TABLE #a 
(
    ClientName VARCHAR(50), 
    JobName VARCHAR(50), 
    JobPartner VARCHAR(40), 
    [Date] DATETIME, 
    GenAdj MONEY, 
    FC MONEY, 
    BadDebt MONEY, 
    nomid INT
)

SELECT 
    C.searchname AS 'CLIENT NAME',
    n.date AS 'DATE',
    SUM(CASE WHEN NOMTYPEID=3 AND NOMSUBTYPEID=2 THEN TOTAL else 0 END) AS 'GENERAL ADJUSTMENTS',
    SUM(CASE WHEN NOMTYPEID=3 AND NOMSUBTYPEID=1 THEN TOTAL else 0 END) AS 'FINANCE CHARGES',
    SUM(CASE WHEN NOMTYPEID=3 AND NOMSUBTYPEID=0 THEN TOTAL else 0 END) AS 'BAD DEBTS',
    sl.serviceline AS 'DEPARTMENT',
    p.name AS 'PARTNER NAME'
FROM 
    tblNominal N
JOIN 
    tblNominalAccs A ON N.ContNominalID = A.NominalID
JOIN
    tblclient C on N.clientid = C.clientid
LEFT JOIN 
    tbljob j ON n.jobid = j.JobID
LEFT JOIN 
    tblpartner p ON j.PartnerID = p.PartnerID
LEFT JOIN 
    tbljobtype jt ON j.jobtypeid = jt.jobtypeid 
LEFT JOIN 
    tblserviceline sl ON j.servicelineid = sl.servicelineid
WHERE 
    Date >= @startdate AND DATE <= @LASTDATE
GROUP BY 
    C.searchname, n.date, sl.serviceline, p.name
ORDER BY 
    'CLIENT NAME' asc, 'FINANCE CHARGES' asc

DROP TABLE #a
```

I think I may be overthinking this. How can I delete the rows with all zeros?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: you need to use `having` after `group by`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use a `HAVING` clause after your `GROUP BY` but before your `ORDER BY`:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN NOMTYPEID=3 AND NOMSUBTYPEID=2 THEN TOTAL else 0 END) > 0
    OR SUM(CASE WHEN NOMTYPEID=3 AND NOMSUBTYPEID=1 THEN TOTAL else 0 END) > 0
    OR SUM(CASE WHEN NOMTYPEID=3 AND NOMSUBTYPEID=0 THEN TOTAL else 0 END) > 0
```

`HAVING` is kind of like a `WHERE` for group results.

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar.  I knew it was simple...Just needed to use HAVING.  Works perfect.  Thank you!